# 0 missing while printing remainder

Tags: c++

I have an operation that stores the value of remainder however if the remainder comes out to be say 0291 it stores only the 291 so i want the variable to store the 0 as well.

Operation:

```
lk = ((lk + tc + vc) * 1671) % 10000;
```

with lk of long int type

Comment: This is has nothing to do with how it's stored. It's how you want to print it.

Comment: So you want to print it as four digits?

Comment: i am printing it on a textbox as *TextBox4 << lk

Comment: @chris this is exactly what i want

Comment: @EmmaRochweel, Ah, does your textbox support those formatting flags?

Comment: i have created the textbox using the wxwidgets

Comment: @EmmaRochweel, I found this: `#include <iostream>

    wxTextCtrl *control = new wxTextCtrl(...);

    wxStreamToTextRedirector redirect(control);

    // all output to cout goes into the text control until the exit from
    // current scope` on [this page](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_text_ctrl.html). I don't suppose that helps at all? I would imagine that using `cout << setw(4)` would transfer directly after that if it isn't already supported.

Comment: Alternatively, is there any way to set the contents of the box to something convertible from `std::string`? In that case just use a stringstream and set the box's conntents based on that.

Comment: The problem here is i huess about the storage when i debug the program i can see that the variable only stores 291 ad not 0291 so if i can store 0291 instead of 291 that would do fine as well

Comment: @Emma - It is actually stored as `100100011` in binary. Everything else is how you (or the debugger) display it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter how many leading zeros you put in front of it, it's still 291. This has nothing to do with the modulus operator, or any math operations.

What you're asking is how the number *is displayed*.

Try this:

```
printf("%04ld", lk);
```

Source: [`man printf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf)

Comment: i am using c++ and i want to print this in a text box , i am simple printing it as : *TextBox4 << lk;

Comment: What kind of textbox are you printing it to?  Perhaps it supports [`std::setw`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setw/) ?

Comment: If you want streams you can use manipulators, e.g. `os << setfill('0') << setw(4) << value`.  These are in the header `<iomanip>`.

Comment: the only candidates supported in my textbox are :
(const wxString&)

operator<<(int)
wxTextCtrlBase::operator<<(long int)
wxTextCtrlBase::operator<<(float)
wxTextCtrlBase::operator<<(double)
wxTextCtrlBase::operator<<(wxChar)

Comment: Well then you need not concern yourself what what you're passing in, but rather the implementation of your TextBox. It needs to be able to configure how the number is displayed.

Comment: Using the `std::ostringstream` type for instance (`<sstream>` header) you can create a formatted `std::string` and then most likely use that to construct a `wxString` that your text box will accept.  Or, allocate some bytes and call `snprintf()` to format.